# Can I make a boot drive with my desktop

Tags: filesystem, flash

I want to make a boot drive with all of the system files the same as the files on my desktop. I want to just plug it in and have it boot up with all my settings and files and everything running when I log in.

I've created a boot disk on the flash drive I want to use but I can't copy my desktop's file system to the flash drive's while its running, and the drive's file system doesn't look anything like the system on the computer when running from my desktop. Instead of having the "bin,boot,cdrom,etc." the flash drive has "boot,casper,dists,EFI,etc."

Is there a way that I can just copy all the files from my computer to the flash drive to make them the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at this: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html.  Be careful, though I have never done this and I advise you to proceed with caution.